# Surface parameterization of a cylinder?

Tags: surfaces

Suppose I wanted to parameterize the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = R^2$ (for the purpose of computing a surface integral).

Say $z$ is in range $-z_0 \le z \le z_0$.

The standard parameterization I see everywhere is $G(\theta,z) = <Rcos(\theta), Rsin(\theta),z>$, where $0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$, and $-z_0 \le z \le z_0$.

My question is that is,
$G(\theta,r) = <rcos(\theta), rsin(\theta), 2z_0>$ another valid parameterization, where $0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$ and $0 \le r \le R$.

I understand the first parameterization you trace out a circle and just give it a height, but in theory the second parameterization is accomplishing the same goal in a slightly different manner by fixing the height and tracing out the circle. The only issue might be if the height of cylinder is infinite then I'm not sure how the second parameterization would take that into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second parametrization does not trace out the surface of a cylinder, but instead gives a disk of radius $R$ in the $z=2z_0$ plane, centered on the $z$-axis.

Comment: Right, that makes sense, I was thinking about it the wrong way.